# Meteor: Turning email address into MD5hash on server, and accessing on client

Tags: javascript, meteor, server, gravatar

So I want to use Gravatar avatars on my website. I got the appropriate packages for it. The way it works, it turns email addresses into an "MD5Hash." That's sent to Gravatar in exchange for the image url.

Fine, but I want to display avatars without exposing everyone's email address. At the same time, I have users already that likely already have gravatars, and I think it would be cool if their avatars just popped up one day, without adding another field to the user profiles collection, or asking them to.

Is there a way to do some of this on the server and accomplish my goal?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("gravatar", function(id){
    var email = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: id}).emails[0].address;
    var options = { 
        secure: true,
        size: 29,
        default: 'retro'
    };

    var md5Hash = Gravatar.hash(email);
    // 5658ffccee7f0ebfda2b226238b1eb6e

    var url = Gravatar.imageUrl(md5Hash, options);
    // https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/5658ffccee7f0ebfda2b226238b1eb6e
    return url;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hackish:**

On the server:

```
userArray = Meteor.users.find(query,{fields: {"emails.address": 1}}).fetch();
userArray.forEach(function(el,i,a){
  a[i] = { _id: el._id, md5hash: Gravatar.hash(el.emails[0].address) };
}
```

where `query` is whatever your criteria are, will get you an *array* of objects whose `_id` matches the `_id` of each user and whose `md5hash` value is the hash of that user's email. You can set up a method to return this array to you when you need it.

The good news is that your client can use these hashes to get avatars in whatever sizes might be necessary at any time.

**Much less hackish:**

The problem with the above is that your server is frequently going to be recomputing the md5hash of each email. Plus you're getting a potentially big and non-reactive array from the server. You'll live to regret this. You really just want to add an `md5hash` key to the `emails` array in the user document, initialize it for existing users, and make sure that new users always have this key set at creation time. This will let you handle either single-email address users or multiple-email address users.

Comment: Thanks for both giving me what I asked for and telling me not to do it. I'm not even going to test it because I see the reason in the second part of your answer. The thing is ... my data isn't really normalized in most places, so it looks like I'll also have to duplicate that hash to each user comment, etc. (along with the userId and username). That's fine ... unless you also see a reason not to do that.

Comment: If you're publishing the information for the users who are referenced by the posts collection then you can easily have a template helper that gets you the avatar for the user in the post. That simple lookup should be plenty fast in minimongo on the client for reasonable numbers of users.

Comment: Well, I wasn't publishing that info already. That's something I haven't attempted yet. In these cases I've just duplicated that info. Out of laziness, yes, but it's faster anyway, right? So says Mongo. I'm not expecting users to complain about wanting old content to reflect their profile changes. I've only got 70 or so users and a handful of content from each so far, anyway.

Comment: Also, seems like it would be kind of difficult to combine with infinite scroll.

Comment: The nice thing about gravatar is that even if a user changes their email address the association of their picture with their *previous* email addresses tends to stick around. This should make your denormalized approach *good enough.* It's quite possible to have infinite scroll and only load data from a subscription as its needed - see http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Infinite_Scrolling The [publish-composite](https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite) package should be useful to you as well.

Comment: That publish-composite package is definitely something I need. I had figured out infinite scrolling, but never got into how to display children of children in a template, with or without the scrolling. Thanks again.